# The "frog pond" theory

Tags: self-study, multilevel-analysis

I have not understood the `frog pond` theory .

The `frog pond` theory refers to the notion that a specific individual frog may be a medium sized frog in a pond otherwise filled with large frogs , or a medium sized frog in a pond otherwise filled with small frogs .

- If a frog is found to be medium sized in a pond , others frogs of the pond can be medium sized , small sized or large sized .

Can you please make the `frog pond` theory easy to me ?

Comment: this is only slightly relevant here, as it is moslty an educational/social sci, not a statistical, concept (well, maybe somewhat as within-group autocorrelation). It says that you set your standards to the average in your group more so than to your 'actual' intellectual abilities, thus a talented student from a poor group would perform worse than a bad student in an excellent group.

Comment: Can anyone suggest to me how a term used to describe a theory from the *sociology of education* is on topic here? I can only assume I've missed something.

Comment: @ Katya, This question is only slightly relevant here, but I want to highlight something about the fact that the frog pond theory explains why we need to be careful when getting to the best model using tests like AIC which are relative. You might see improvement in given 10 models but they might all be bad models.

Answer (score 3):

I can explain it using salary distribution in groups. If you look at a person with medium level salary in one country, then that person can be in some European country where salary is ridiculously high and this person is rich by universal standard, or he can be in a poor country where everyone is poor and this person is also poor, or he can be in an average country and this person has average salary.

So, what is the focus here? Essentially, we cannot say that the position of an object in a group does not represent the position of group members in a global sense. And likewise you cannot compare the top employee of a company with medium employee of another. Because that will be comparing apple and oranges unless you know their status in global picture. I hope I didn't just confuse you more.

The main idea should be something like this: when explaining a variable varying in different groups, one cannot describe that variable properly just by the local ranking, a global ranking is a requirement for a study across whole dataset.

Comment: But not understanding what is `local` and what is `global` in your example ?